# How to add multiple set of marker?

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, ngx-leaflet

I need to have multiple layer of icons drawed on my map. Each set of that icon must be rendered or not by clicking on the option panel.
I found all examples that shown how to add a single marker or a group of markers, but nothing about a plurality of groups.

i'm working in angular with Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet but ithink the concept i missing i think is for all implementation.

```
  markersLayersLev_1: Marker[] = [];
  markersLayersLev_2: Marker[] = [];
  markersLayersLev_3: Marker[] = [];
```

How can i put this "layers" in separate manner on the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do this task.

Marker extends Layer so I can insert these markers in LayerGroup.
I have various `layerGroup`, each one with its own set of markers.

the ngx-leaflet leafletLayers directive accepts an array of layers, so I put the various `layerGroup` in a `LayerGroup[]` array and I set this to the value of the directive.

In Typescript file:

```
itemsLevel_1: LayerGroup = new LayerGroup();
itemsLevel_2: LayerGroup = new LayerGroup();

marker1.addTo(itemsLevel_1);
marker2.addTo(itemsLevel_1);

marker3.addTo(itemsLevel_2);
marker4.addTo(itemsLevel_2);

 layerMainGroup: LayerGroup[] = [
    itemsLevel_1,
    itemsLevel_2
  ];
```

and in the html page:

```
<div
  id="mapContainer"
  leaflet
  [...]
  [leafletLayers]="layerMainGroup"
></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can accept your own answer :).